# how to show time in well format in adapter

Tags: android

im loading database value in adapter and show in listview but problem is listview display full format  like   22/11/2013  11:19   i wqant to show only hour and minute so how do i format my this line  holder.msgtext3.setText("" + msglist.get(position).getTime()); to show only hour and minute in textvew? any idea?

```
            public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MessageModel> {

Activity context;
List<MessageModel> msglist;
ViewHolder holder;



public MessageAdapter(Activity context, List<MessageModel> dealList) {
    super(context, R.layout.msgrow, dealList);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.msglist = dealList;
}

class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView msgtext, timemsg   ,msgtext2 ,msgtext3;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.msgrow, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
viewHolder.msgtext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.msgDatatextview);


viewHolder.msgtext3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.msgDatatextview3);




        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }


    msglist.get(position).getTime();

    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.msgtext.setText("" + msglist.get(position).getMsg());

    holder.msgtext3.setText("" + msglist.get(position).getTime());

    return view;
   }

 }
```

Comment: how do i show here  holder.msgtext3.setText("" + msglist.get(position).getTime());  only  hour and minute????

Comment: Look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). It helps in converting to any particular date format. Look at [SO posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=simpledateformat) for `SimpleDateFormat` usages.